# LocaleMiddleware not selecting requested available language

Tags: django

I am having trouble making `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` set Chinese language as per the cookies/header I specify in the request.

After some debugging, I have narrowed it down to the the following function, which rejects it

`django.utils.translations.trans_real.check_for_language`

`all_locale_paths` returns only django's locales, which do not contain 'cn'. My apps are packaged and installed separately from the project itself, and they provide their own 'cn' language files, which get discovered successfully, but since their locale directories are not specified in `LOCALE_PATHS`, the middleware does not check them.

What is the best approach to avoid this problem? I am not adding the `LOCALE_PATHS`, as the app locations differ based on the different environments the project is deployed. I could import the app, and find the paths from it, but that seems like an overkill.

Comment: "cn" isn't the language code for Chinese, it's "zh" ("zh_Hans" or "zh_Hant"), as specified by ISO-639. Your browser should set "zh" as Accept-Language header if you set your language to Chinese.

Comment: Thank you, changing to zh_Hans fixed the issue, as it is available in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses ISO-639 language codes (not country codes), which is also what browsers use in their `Accept-Language` headers.

The language code for Chinese is "zh", in Django both variants "zh_Hans" and "zh_Hant" are supported. "cn" isn't a language code for Chinese.